# SQLAlchemy: SAWarning: fully NULL primary key identity cannot load any object

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I am currently working on a tutorial on Flask.
The task at hand is creating an /edit route for a "favorite movies database"
I have, I think, correct code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '8BYkEfBA6O6donzWlSihBXox7C0sKR6b'
Bootstrap(app)

##CREATE DATABASE of MOVIES
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "sqlite:///movies.db"
# Optional: But it will silence the deprecation warning in the console.
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


##CREATE A NEW TABLE
class Movie(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(250), unique=True, nullable=False)
    year = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=False, nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String(250), unique=True, nullable=False)
    rating = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    ranking = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    review = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    img_url = db.Column(db.String(250), unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __repr__ (self):
        return f'<Movie  {self.title}>'


#
# db.create_all()

# new_movie = Movie(
#     id = 1,
#     title="Phone Booth",
#     year=2002,
#     description="Publicist Stuart Shepard finds himself trapped in a phone booth, pinned down by an extortionist's sniper rifle. Unable to leave or receive outside help, Stuart's negotiation with the caller leads to a jaw-dropping climax.",
#     rating=7.3,
#     ranking=10,
#     review="My favourite character was the caller.",
#     img_url="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/tjrX2oWRCM3Tvarz38zlZM7Uc10.jpg"
# )

# db.session.add(new_movie)
# db.session.commit()

# Create Form
class RateMovieForm(FlaskForm):
    rating = StringField("Your Rating Out of 10")
    review = StringField("Your Review")
    submit = SubmitField("Done")


@app.route("/")
def home ():
    all_movies = db.session.query(Movie).all()
    return render_template("index.html", movies=all_movies)


@app.route('/edit', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def rate_movie ():
    form = RateMovieForm()
    movie_id= request.args.get("id")
    movie = Movie.query.get(movie_id)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        movie.rating = float(form.rating.data)
        movie.review = str(form.review.data)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template("edit.html", movie=movie, form=form)


@app.route('/delete')
def delete ():
    movie_id = request.args.get('id')
    movie_to_delete = Movie.query.get(movie_id)
    db.session.delete(movie_to_delete)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('home'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

With the accompanying form in edit.html:

```
  <form>
    {{wtf.form_field(form.rating)}}
    {{wtf.form_field(form.review)}}
    {{wtf.form_field(form.submit)}}
  </form>
```

When I run the main.py (above python code), I receive the warning in the title:

```
SAWarning: fully NULL primary key identity cannot load any object.  This condition may raise an error in a future release.
```

and the edit-process is not completed.
The connection to the form works just fine.
Can anyone help me/see what I am missing?

All the best,
Kevin

Edit1: After the suggested change:

```
 movie_id = request.args.get('id')
```

to

```
movie_id = request.args['id']
```

I receive the following error:

```
400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'id'
```

I also included a screenshot (DB Browser for SQLite view on database) so that you can see the data ...
[database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsafR.png)

Comment: This line: `movie_id= request.args.get("id")` will return `None` if `"id"` doesn't exist as query parameter. Change it to `request.args["id"]` and it will throw an error if the parameter doesn't exist, then at least you'll know if that is the issue.

Comment: exactly this line is throwing an error after the change. I'll update my post!